# Ventana Overlay Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, plugin, extensión-google-chrome

Hola intentando aprender y jugar con el desarrollo de Plugins en Google Chrome y me ha surgido la siguiente duda.

> manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Example Overlay",
    "description": "Testing an Overaly in JS",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "./view/index.html",
        "default_title": "PLUGIN EXAMPLE"
    }

}
```

Mi intención es hacer un plugin que al clickear en el ocupe el 100% de la pantalla del usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo incrementar el tamaño, el ancho y el alto desde el css... Pero he probando con `100%`, `100vw` o `1920px`... pero no funciona sobre los `600-800px` ya no aumenta independientemente del valor que pongas.

¿Cómo podría realizar una aplicación que deseo que se ejecute como overlay de Google Chrome?

¿Como puedo cubrir la ventana de Google Chrome completamente con un overlay? Asignando 100% o 100vw al width no funciona...

Comment: He quitado la última pregunta porque convertía la publicación en algo subjetivo y basado en opiniones, pero si lo que preguntas es sólo cómo conseguir que se ocupe toda la ventana de Chrome, es algo más objetivo. Aparte de eso, ¿qué es lo que quieres que se cubra? ¿El viewport? ¿la pantalla completa de Chrome (incluyendo botones y barra de direcciones, etc?

Comment: Si puede ser todo mejor.